# Mercurial mirror: abort: No such file or directory: http://[...]/00manifest.i

Tags: apache-http-server, http, mercurial, repository, mirroring

I am trying to setup a daily mirror of a mercurial repository - code.python.org in particular - within our local network, and serve that via Apache HTTPD.

On the remote host that hosts apache, I did this:

```
$ cd /var/www
$ hg clone http://code.python.org/hg/trunk/
```

On my macbook, I ran:

```
$ hg -v clone http://remote/trunk/
(falling back to static-http)
abort: No such file or directory: http://remote/trunk/.hg/store/00manifest.i
```

Google does not show any relevant result for this particular error. I remember back in those days being able to setup Bazaar mirrors by a simple clone. Doesn't Mercurial work like that? How do I setup a mirror that must further act like a clone URL?

Comment: Sanity check: does `http://remote/trunk/.hg/store/00manifest.i` exist?  Is it accessible?

Comment: @Stephen yup, it can be accessed via HTTP; and also has others+read permission on the filesystem itself.

Comment: I wonder if mercurial can be made to print a stack-trace (`-v` didn't work for me), so I can take a look at the root cause of this issue myself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug with static-http (static-http is slow and should be avoided whenever possible). But you should preferably use hgweb (serve mercurial with a cgi or wsgi).

See http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories for instructions.

Comment: Being slow is a trade-off I am willing to make given the simplicity of server setup.